# How to redirect with query string in Nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, rewrite, querystring

I would like to redirect:

```
something.com/search?keywords='value'
```

to

```
something.com/search?q='value'
```

Here is my Nginx config:

```
location ~ /search {
       if ($args ~* "keywords=(.*)") {
            rewrite ^.*$ /search?q=$arg_keywords permanent;
        }
    }
```

But the `q` parameter is empty on redirection.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> But the q parameter is empty on redirection.

I don't see that problem. When I test the configuration as written, it creates a redirection loop because the original `keywords='value'` is appended to the rewritten URI.

You can prevent `rewrite` from including any original parameters by appending a `?` to the rewritten URI.

For example:

```
rewrite ^ /search?q=$arg_keywords? permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.